# $\text{span} \left ( \vec{u_{1}},\vec{u_{2}},\vec{u_{3}}, \vec{v} \right ) = \text{span} \left ( \vec{u_{1}},\vec{u_{2}},\vec{u_{3}} \right )?$

Tags: linear-algebra

Suppose $\vec{v}$ is a linear combination of $\vec{u_{1}},\vec{u_{2}},\vec{u_{3}}$. Is it always true that $$\text{span} \left ( \vec{u_{1}},\vec{u_{2}},\vec{u_{3}}, \vec{v} \right ) = \text{span} \left ( \vec{u_{1}},\vec{u_{2}},\vec{u_{3}} \right )?$$

Might be a stupid question, but im not really sure how to explain.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes ! First of all, if $A \subset B$ then $\text{span}A \subset \text{span}B$

So $\text{span}(u_1,u_2,u_3) \subset \text{span}(u_1,u_2,u_3,v)$

On the other hand, $v \in \text{span}(u_1,u_2,u_3,v)$ and by hypothesis, $v=a_1u_1+a_2u_2+a_3u_3$ implies $v \in \text{span}(u_1,u_2,u_3)$

Answer (score 0):

Yes.  $v\in \operatorname{span}\{u_1,u_2,u_3\}$.  The result follows.